# R POS tagging and tokenizing in one go

Tags: r, tokenize, pos-tagger, tidytext

I have a text as below.

```
   Section <- c("If an infusion reaction occurs, interrupt the infusion.")
    df <- data.frame(Section)
```

When I tokenize using tidytext and the code below,

```
AA <- df %>%
  mutate(tokens = str_extract_all(df$Section, "([^\\s]+)"),
         locations = str_locate_all(df$Section, "([^\\s]+)"),
         locations = map(locations, as.data.frame)) %>%
  select(-Section) %>%
  unnest(tokens, locations)
```

It gives me the tokens, the start and end position. How do I obtain the POS tags while unnesting at the same time. Something as below (the POStags may not be correct in the image below)

[image]

Comment: Just use the udpipe R package: example vignette at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-annotation.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package udpipe to get your POS data. Udpipe automatically tokenizes punctuation.

```
Section <- c("If an infusion reaction occurs, interrupt the infusion.")
df <- data.frame(Section, stringAsFactors = FALSE)

library(udpipe)
library(dplyr)
udmodel <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
udmodel <- udpipe_load_model(file = udmodel$file_model)


x <- udpipe_annotate(udmodel, 
                     df$Section)
x <- as.data.frame(x)

x %>% select(token, upos)
       token  upos
1         If SCONJ
2         an   DET
3   infusion  NOUN
4   reaction  NOUN
5     occurs  NOUN
6          , PUNCT
7  interrupt  VERB
8        the   DET
9   infusion  NOUN
10         . PUNCT
```

Now to combine this the result of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850625/tokenizing-issue) you asked. I took one of the answers.

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% mutate(
  tokens = str_extract_all(Section, "\\w+|[[:punct:]]"),
  locations = str_locate_all(Section, "\\w+|[[:punct:]]"),
  locations = map(locations, as.data.frame)) %>%
  select(-Section) %>%
  unnest(tokens, locations) %>% 
  mutate(POS = purrr::map_chr(tokens, function(x) as.data.frame(udpipe_annotate(udmodel, x = x, tokenizer = "vertical"))$upos))

       tokens start end  upos
1         If     1   2 SCONJ
2         an     4   5   DET
3   infusion     7  14  NOUN
4   reaction    16  23  NOUN
5     occurs    25  30  NOUN
6          ,    31  31 PUNCT
7  interrupt    33  41  VERB
8        the    43  45   DET
9   infusion    47  54  NOUN
10         .    55  55 PUNCT
```

**edit: better solution**

But the best solution would be to start from udpipe and then do the rest. Note that I am using stringi instead of stringr package. stringr is based on stringi, but stringi has more options.

```
x <- udpipe_annotate(udmodel, x = df$Section)

x %>% 
  as_data_frame %>% 
  select(token, POSTag = upos) %>% # select needed columns
  # add start/end locations
  mutate(locations = map(token, function(x) data.frame(stringi::stri_locate(df$Section, fixed = x)))) %>% 
  unnest

  # A tibble: 10 x 4
   token     POSTag start   end
   <chr>     <chr>  <int> <int>
 1 If        SCONJ      1     2
 2 an        DET        4     5
 3 infusion  NOUN       7    14
 4 reaction  NOUN      16    23
 5 occurs    NOUN      25    30
 6 ,         PUNCT     31    31
 7 interrupt VERB      33    41
 8 the       DET       43    45
 9 infusion  NOUN       7    14
10 .         PUNCT     55    55
```

Comment: FYI. You can also use the udpipe R package to get parts of speech tags for already tokenised text. Example is shown at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-annotation.html#annotate_your_text where it says 'My text data is already tokenised'. For this use the argument tokenizer = 'vertical'. That avoids doing crazy things with a join as you get the same number of rows in the same order back as the number of tokens you provide.

Comment: @jwijffels, I had forgotten about this part of udpipe. I changed the answer a bit to show this part. And I added a start from udpipe. as that reduces the code part a lot.

Answer (score 3):

FYI. Since udpipe version 0.7 on CRAN, you can just do as follows.

```
library(udpipe)
x <- data.frame(doc_id = c("doc1", "doc2"),
                text = c("If an infusion reaction occurs, interrupt the infusion.",
                         "Houston we have a problem"))
x <- udpipe(x, "english")
x
```

which gives you (notice the start/end as well as the token/upos/xpos which you are looking for):

```
 doc_id paragraph_id sentence_id start end term_id token_id     token     lemma  upos xpos                                      feats head_token_id   dep_rel deps            misc
   doc1            1           1     1   2       1        1        If        if SCONJ   IN                                       <NA>             7      mark <NA>            <NA>
   doc1            1           1     4   5       2        2        an         a   DET   DT                  Definite=Ind|PronType=Art             5       det <NA>            <NA>
   doc1            1           1     7  14       3        3  infusion  infusion  NOUN   NN                                Number=Sing             4  compound <NA>            <NA>
   doc1            1           1    16  23       4        4  reaction  reaction  NOUN   NN                                Number=Sing             5  compound <NA>            <NA>
   doc1            1           1    25  30       5        5    occurs     occur  NOUN  NNS                                Number=Plur             7     nsubj <NA>   SpaceAfter=No
   doc1            1           1    31  31       6        6         ,         , PUNCT    ,                                       <NA>             7     punct <NA>            <NA>
   doc1            1           1    33  41       7        7 interrupt interrupt  VERB   VB                      Mood=Imp|VerbForm=Fin             0      root <NA>            <NA>
   doc1            1           1    43  45       8        8       the       the   DET   DT                  Definite=Def|PronType=Art             9       det <NA>            <NA>
   doc1            1           1    47  54       9        9  infusion  infusion  NOUN   NN                                Number=Sing             7       obj <NA>   SpaceAfter=No
   doc1            1           1    55  55      10       10         .         . PUNCT    .                                       <NA>             7     punct <NA> SpacesAfter=\\n
   doc2            1           1     1   7       1        1   Houston   Houston PROPN  NNP                                Number=Sing             0      root <NA>            <NA>
   doc2            1           1     9  10       2        2        we        we  PRON  PRP Case=Nom|Number=Plur|Person=1|PronType=Prs             3     nsubj <NA>            <NA>
   doc2            1           1    12  15       3        3      have      have  VERB  VBP           Mood=Ind|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin             1 parataxis <NA>            <NA>
   doc2            1           1    17  17       4        4         a         a   DET   DT                  Definite=Ind|PronType=Art             5       det <NA>            <NA>
   doc2            1           1    19  25       5        5   problem   problem  NOUN   NN                                Number=Sing             3       obj <NA> SpacesAfter=\\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answerer, I think that udpipe is likely the easiest way to go for POS tagging. My favorite way to interact with udpipe is via the [cleanNLP](https://github.com/statsmaths/cleanNLP) package. After the initializing function is called, it is just two lines of code to get the udpipe output.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cleanNLP)

cnlp_init_udpipe()
#> Loading required namespace: udpipe

df <- data_frame(id = 1,
                 text = c("If an infusion reaction occurs, interrupt the infusion."))

cnlp_annotate(df) %>%
  cnlp_get_tif()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 19
#>    id      sid   tid word  lemma upos  pos     cid   pid definite mood 
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int> <chr>    <chr>
#>  1 1         1     1 If    if    SCONJ IN        0     1 <NA>     <NA> 
#>  2 1         1     2 an    a     DET   DT        3     1 Ind      <NA> 
#>  3 1         1     3 infu… infu… NOUN  NN        6     1 <NA>     <NA> 
#>  4 1         1     4 reac… reac… NOUN  NN       15     1 <NA>     <NA> 
#>  5 1         1     5 occu… occur NOUN  NNS      24     1 <NA>     <NA> 
#>  6 1         1     6 ,     ,     PUNCT ,        30     1 <NA>     <NA> 
#>  7 1         1     7 inte… inte… VERB  VB       32     1 <NA>     Imp  
#>  8 1         1     8 the   the   DET   DT       42     1 Def      <NA> 
#>  9 1         1     9 infu… infu… NOUN  NN       46     1 <NA>     <NA> 
#> 10 1         1    10 .     .     PUNCT .        54     1 <NA>     <NA> 
#> # ... with 8 more variables: number <chr>, pron_type <chr>,
#> #   verb_form <chr>, source <int>, relation <chr>, word_source <chr>,
#> #   lemma_source <chr>, spaces <dbl>
```

Created on 2018-08-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).